# One anchor tag not working, similar anchor tags working

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I've a `<li>` element with 3 pretty similar anchor tags. The first two work just fine as they should but the third doesn't: it does change its color upon `hover` but it's not clickable. This behavior is similar for Google Chrome, Firefox and IE11 so it's probably not the browser. I've a ton of similar pages and never encountered any such trouble previously.

The LIVE page is [here](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/mean-center-many-variables/comment-page-7/#comments), <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> gets you to the final comment, the final `<a>` of which is the problem.

The underlying HTML for this section is

```html
<ul id='commentul'>
  <li>
    <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/72f74d7bd6a20a2f9dd37e6af9d45850?s=80&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/72f74d7bd6a20a2f9dd37e6af9d45850?s=160&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-80 photo' height='80' width='80' /> <h3>By Eszter Babarczy on July 30th, 2016</h3>
    <p>Hi! I ran the dialogue with 21 variables using their names. The program insists these are string variables (although they are set to scale). What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!</p>
  </li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li>
    <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3bd63d9e0384df2d2e5cc82890712aaa?s=80&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3bd63d9e0384df2d2e5cc82890712aaa?s=160&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-80 photo' height='80' width='80' /> <h3>By <a href='http://www.spss-tutorials.com/about-us/' rel='nofollow'>Ruben Geert van den Berg</a> on July 31st, 2016</h3>
    <p>Hi Eszter!</p>
    <p>Try and run <a href="http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-descriptives-command/" rel="nofollow">DESCRIPTIVES</a> on all relevant variables. SPSS will (rightfully) refuse to generate descriptives for string variables and throw a warning.</p>
    <p>Now, in SPSS, you can have string variables set to scale. It doesn't make sense, though. "Scale" in SPSS means that you're dealing with a metric variable (the <a href="http://www.spss-tutorials.com/measurement-levels/">measurement level</a> is interval or ratio). </p>
    <p>The defining characteristic of metric variables is that numeric calculations (sum, mean) are meaningful for them and such calculations are not possible on string variables. So we usually see that "scale" is only used for numeric variables whereas all string variables are set to nominal but perhaps this doesn't hold for your data.</p>
    <p>A tiny example illustrating this point is <a  href="http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-syntax-examples/no-descriptives-for-metric-string-variable.html">No Descriptives for Metric String Variable</a>. If that doesn't hold for your data, please get back at me, ok?</p>
  </li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ul><!-- id='commentul'> -->
```

Comment: That is the current page number, actually that is a span, not a href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last anchor `a` you have a `&nbsp;` inside the tag, like this: `<a &nbsp;href="..."`

Remove that and it will work

Comment: Thanks man!! I didn't see the `&nbsp;` anywhere in the source code in Google Chrome. However, **I removed the (single) space in the Wordpress UI and then put it back** and updated the comment. That fixed the problem -although I still don't really see how things went wrong in the first place.